# Issue while setting HTTP header through AFNetwokring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, afnetworking-2

**Problem:**

```
- (void) getReportSummaryWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(bool success))success {

        NSString *storedToken = [[User sharedUser] accessToken];
        NSLog(@"Stored Class: %@",[storedToken class]);
        //Logs -- __NSCFString
        NSString *constantToken = @"e5c47aa3-c168-480b-a10c-1c4379096fbf";
        NSLog(@"Constant Class: %@",[constantToken class]);
        //Logs -- __NSCFConstantString
        [self.manager.requestSerializer setValue:constantToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        //[self.manager.requestSerializer setValue:storedToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

        [self.manager GET:someURLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
            success(YES);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            success(NO);
        }];
```

When I log value of storedToken it prints ***"e5c47aa3-c168-480b-a10c-1c4379096fbf"***

And constantToken prints ***e5c47aa3-c168-480b-a10c-1c4379096fbf*** withtout **"**.

When I use **constantToken** the server responds correctly but when I use **storedToken** the server reponse is not correct.

**Question:**

Now is there workaround for this issue? Anyway to cast NSCFString into NSCFConstantString ?

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: You are storing `storedToken` as `@"\"xxx-yyy-zzz-bla-bla\""` please save it correctly or ask server to send you the string without double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You are storing `storedToken` as `@"\"xxx-yyy-zzz-bla-bla\""` please save it correctly or ask server to send you the string without double quotes

For the time being what you can do is to trim the `"`, you can also replace `"` with empty sting but I won't recommend that

```
NSString *goodToken = [storedToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""]];
NSLog(@"%@", goodToken);
```

#### P.S.

> This should be seen as a temporary fix, you should save token which don't have the double quotes. Please look onto the code and find why you're getting double quotes, might be your server is sending you the string with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *storedToken = [[User sharedUser] accessToken];
NSString *tokenWithoutQuote = [storedToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

So this solved the problem. Yea as **@Inder Kumar Rathore** pointed storedToken was stored as `@"\"xxx-yyy-zzz-bla-bla\""`

Answer (score -1):

`NSCFConstantString` is an implementation of `NSString` and it keeps the string data in code memory.

The `NSCFString`s are actually toll-free bridging strings that can act as `CFString` in `Core Foundation` Land as well as `NSString` in `Objective-C` land.

You can refer [NSString Optimizations](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/03/beware-of-nsstring-optimizations/) for more refrence.